# Initialize value for model inside the Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, razor-pages

I have one model and want to use it for three Razor pages. The only difference is one integer defined public in the model that I need to set differently for each page. I tried:

```
@model IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
    Model.type = 0;
}
```

`type` is the value I'm trying to set, but I need it for the `OnGetAsync` method of the model, which is executed just after `@model IndexModel`. Is there a way to define it as part of the initialization of the model?

Or maybe if there is a way to get the Razor page the model is being referenced from, I could set the value accordingly for each case.

Comment: I imagine you would set the value in the controller or in the model itself, not in the view.

Comment: Sure, I wouldn't mind, but I need to set it differently according to which view.

Comment: Why can't you know that in the controller?  Surely the controller knows which view it's directing the user to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you should be doing this in the controller, not in your views.   You can do that as follows:

```
    public ActionResult View1()
    {
        MyModel model = new MyModel();
        model.Type = 1;
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult View2()
    {
        MyModel model = new MyModel();
        model.Type = 2;
        return View(model);
    }
```